# Normal looking text file, detected by file as ASCII Pascal program text

Tags: files

I have a "normal" looking text file (contains english sentences) which is getting detected by `file` command as `ASCII Pascal program text`.

How does Pascal program text differentiate itself from normal ASCII English text?

I did `head -10 file > tmp`

`file tmp` still shows `Pascal`. 
`tmp` when opened in VI and `:set list`

```
HELEN'S BABIES$
$
With some account of their ways, innocent, crafty, angelic, impish,$
witching and impulsive; also a partial record of their actions during$
ten days of their existence$
$
By JOHN HABBERTON$
$
$
$
```

Output of `head file | od -c`

```
0000000   H   E   L   E   N   '   S       B   A   B   I   E   S  \n  \n
0000020   W   i   t   h       s   o   m   e       a   c   c   o   u   n
0000040   t       o   f       t   h   e   i   r       w   a   y   s   ,
0000060       i   n   n   o   c   e   n   t   ,       c   r   a   f   t
0000100   y   ,       a   n   g   e   l   i   c   ,       i   m   p   i
0000120   s   h   ,  \n   w   i   t   c   h   i   n   g       a   n   d
0000140       i   m   p   u   l   s   i   v   e   ;       a   l   s   o
0000160       a       p   a   r   t   i   a   l       r   e   c   o   r
0000200   d       o   f       t   h   e   i   r       a   c   t   i   o
0000220   n   s       d   u   r   i   n   g  \n   t   e   n       d   a
0000240   y   s       o   f       t   h   e   i   r       e   x   i   s
0000260   t   e   n   c   e  \n  \n   B   y       J   O   H   N       H
0000300   A   B   B   E   R   T   O   N  \n  \n  \n  \n
0000314
```

File uploaded here: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/L0eCWJTvy/

I'm on `CentOS release 6.5`, `file` version `5.04`

**There is something in the 4th line. Removing from 4th line onwards detects it as only text file**

Comment: Please give us a minimal example of the file that reproduces the issue. Also have a look through `head file | od -c` to check for non-printing characters.

Comment: @terdon done it.

Comment: Thanks. What operating system are you running? Could you provide us with a link where we can download the actual file? There seems to be nothing strange in the `od` output.

Comment: Do you have a `$HOME/.magic` or `$HOME/.magic.mgc` file?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, should i share it? Is there some version number for that file that will make you identify it?

Comment: TBH I don't understand the syntax of the magic file specification - but someone else might. In any case, you could temporarily rename that file to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @steeldriver see edit at the end of question.

Comment: It is reported as ASCII for me. @steeldriver's suggestion about `~/.magic` is probably right on. Did you try running `file` as another use or renaming the `~/.magic` file? That's where `file` reads the filetype patterns it recognizes from.

Comment: Hang on, you said you had a `$HOME/.magic` file. If not, which one are you talking about? `/etc/magic`? That's normal, you're supposed to have it.

Comment: yes, it's `/etc/magic`. not under $home, i just wanted to say that i have the magic file somewhere (it shows path when you do `file -v`)

Comment: Please answer your question yourself with your new findings, and accept it - so it will not stay open forever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able reproduce this both on OS X 10.6.8 and OpenBSD 5.5-current.

Printing out debug information using `file -D tmp`, it turns out that your text file fails roughly 2000 tests before `file(1)` recognizes the Pascal keyword [`record`](http://www.gnu-pascal.org/gpc/record.html#record) and decides that it must be a Pascal program text.

A minimal working example can be obtained as follows:

```
$ echo record > test
$ file test
test: ASCII Pascal program text
```

After numerous heuristics, only the "third & last set of tests, based on hardwired assumptions" in [ascmagic.c](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/file/ascmagic.c?rev=1.12;content-type=text%2Fplain) applies. These tests recognize "file types that we know based on keywords that can appear anywhere in the file". Therefore, minimal changes to your file result in the correct identification as `ASCII English text`, for example changing `their` to `the` in the third line.

Comment: Arch `file-5.19` detects Op's file as _ASCII text_ but your test shows _Pascal source, ASCII text_. After trying `strings /usr/share/file/misc/magic.mgc | grep -C 10 'pascal'` I can see it's _record_ or _program_ at the beginning of a line or _(input,_ anywhere in the text which triggers such identification in my case. +1

Comment: could you have a stab at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140359/test-for-a-particular-file-format? thanks.