# Test for a particular file format

Tags: files, file-format, file-command

This is a followup to [Normal looking text file, detected by file as ASCII Pascal program text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140175/normal-looking-text-file-detected-by-file-as-ascii-pascal-program-text)

It seems `file` can't be trusted all the time.

It seems possible that a particular file may be detected as having both `encoding/format1` and `encoding/format2`. `file` tells me it's `encoding/format1`, but I need to check, whether it also satisfies the constraints of `encoding/format2`.

- Is there a way to do that?
- Is there a way I can ask "Check if this file follows the rules of
  ASCII English Text (or *some other encoding*)" and the answer will be
  "yes" or "no"?

Comment: [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71137/22565)'s an interesting test case for the solutions you obtain :-)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the `--keep-going` (`-k`) option of `file`. It writes out more matching formats.

Related [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) description of this option:

> Don't stop at the first match, keep going.  Subsequent matches will be have the string ‘\012- ’ prepended.  (If you want a
>   newline, see the -r option.)  The magic pattern
>                with the highest strength (see the -l option) comes first.

Comment: thanks, i should have checked manpages. But unfortunately this doesn't work for the file I have uploaded in the linked question. `file -k tmp` still shows only `ASCII Pascal program text` as the only matching format whereas I expect it to match it with `ASCII English Text`.

Comment: file: invalid option -- 'l' @illuminÉ

Comment: @illuminÉ no, the `-l` option just list all patterns with their strengh value, which are unrelated how good they actually fit to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Only answering your second question, as [jofel has already answered the first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140361/90751).

> - Is there a way I can ask "Check if this file follows the rules of ASCII English Text (or some other encoding)" and the answer will be "yes" or "no"?

See the `-e`/`--exclude` option.  From [`file(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html):

> **-e, --exclude** *testname*
>
> Exclude the test named in *testname* from the list of tests made to determine the file type.
>
> [...]
>
> - `soft    Consults magic files`

Those magic files are responsible for the Pascal report, so `-e soft` should be enough.  You could try excluding other tests from that list too, as long as you leave `ascii` enabled.

For your "yes/no" test, combine with `-b` ("brief" ie. without the filename) and `--mime-encoding`, to output only the encoding.  Then it's a simple string comparison:

```
if [ "$(file -b --mime-encoding -e soft $file)" == "us-ascii" ] ; then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```